# Use external library chessboard.js in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I am struggling to load the [chessboard.js](https://chessboardjs.com) library in Svelte and implement the events. An example REPL is [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/6cc9af2285fc477c9628a1b48f58c014?version=3.44.1).

1. I am loading chessboard.js as shown in the following snippet. When the js file is loaded, the function initBoard() is called. In this function, a board object is instantiated.

```js
<svelte:head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chessboard-js/1.0.0/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chessboard-js/1.0.0/chessboard-1.0.0.js" on:load={initBoard}> </script>
</svelte:head>
```

In the initBoard() function, I am trying to instantiate a chessboard object as per the [example](https://chessboardjs.com/examples#1001). However, the board never appears, even though the initBoard() function is called.

2. How would the events like [onDrop()](https://chessboardjs.com/docs.html#config:onDrop) in chessboard.js be best implemented in App.svelte?

Comment: `chessboardjs` relies on `jQuery` so you'll need to import it first. Both packages are available on NPM which means you don't neee the CDN links, but can import them into your component as modules.

Comment: Also, you may want to use a more up to date package such as that developed for lichess: [ornicar/chessground](https://github.com/gtm-nayan/svelte-use-chessground), which also has a svelte wrapper: [gtm-nayan/svelte-use-chessground](https://github.com/gtm-nayan/svelte-use-chessground)

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the hint about including jQuery directly from npm. I've updated the REPL but the problem is still there.

Comment: Here's a 'working' [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2d0581a9859a4ec59c75ba5712611911?version=3.44.1) based on the [onDrop](https://chessboardjs.com/examples#4004) example from the docs. You'll need to resolve the image asset location in your project, and ideally import both jQuery and Chessboardjs as packages rather than relying on the CDN versions.

Comment: Fantastic! This works.

Comment: @pilchard, it looks like you solved the problem, but your answer is in a comment, so this question shows up as still open. Can you post an answer and then mr_js can accept it so that it's in a proper format for StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 'working' [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2d0581a9859a4ec59c75ba5712611911?version=3.44.1) based on the [onDrop example](https://chessboardjs.com/examples#4004) from the docs.

The main reason your attempt wasn't working is that you hadn't imported jQuery.

The above REPL is still using CDN links but ideally you would import both jQuery and Chessboardjs as modules rather than relying on the CDN versions. You will also need to resolve the image asset location in your project.